# How to recreate script beanstalkd in /etc/init.d

Tags: init, beanstalkd

I made a mistake and removed the init script beanstalkd from /etc/init.d. Does somebody know how it can be recreated ?

When I type

> sudo apt-get autoremove beanstalkd

and then re-install it. The script is still not there.

I hope someone can help.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to create it automatically, you'll probably have to entirely remove and purge the package from the system.

A lot easier is to find a copy of the package and then manually copy it back into place, running the appropriate scripts to recreate any links to it to ensure it's autostarted on boot.